# jQuery - set max length for textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to have a textarea with a maximum length, and show the user how many characters are left (as it's done on twitter), but I can't seem to get it to be as good.

The requirements are:

- Must show the current number of characters they've typed
- Must remain accurate when a key is held down
- Must remain accurate when backspace/delete is used
- Must remain accurate when text in the box is selected and cut/delete by using the right click menu
- Must allow the user to go over the limit (I hate it when a field actually prevents me from going over, it makes it harder to edit it down)

Is there a jQuery plugin to do this? Or is there a simple javascript way of doing it (the onChange method doesn't update as they're typing, and keydown/keyup would have troubles with mouse changes)

At the moment it seems like the best way is to have a function to do what I want (check the length and update the message), call it with keydown/keyup/change, and also poll it a few times per second. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

What you usually do is attach multiple event handlers pointing to a validating function, but you won't be able to stop the rightclick/paste with this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myTextArea").live("change keydown keyup keypress", function() {
        validate();
    });
});

function validate() {
    // validates #myTextArea
}
```

Comment: And the `input` event, and `propertychange`

Comment: i belive you don't need `$(document).ready(function() {` if you are using **live**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#textarea").on('input',function(){
    if(this.value.length > 50) {
        alert("u cant input more.");
        this.value = this.value.substring(0,50);
    }
    $('#counter').html(this.value.length + '/50');
});
```

maybe this code help u